# How to save number type instead of string using firestore functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to save number type as number, but my code is saving as string

field on form

```
<TextField required size="small" value={price} label="price" type="number" InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, }} onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
```

invoking as

```
    await fetch('/createItem', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ newProductInfo }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
```

Function:

```
const {newProductInfo} = req.body;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  const {
    id,    title,    imageUrl,    price,
    quantity,    size,    type,   
  } = newProductInfo;
```

converting before add/set

const floatPrice = Number.parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);

and finally the add/set to collection

```
  await store.collection("items").doc(id)
      .set({
        title,
        imageUrl,
        price: floatPrice,
        quantity,
        size,
        type,

      });
```

Output :

[image]

How can I save as number? what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) indicates that it returns a string, so it's not surprising that you're seeing one in Firestore.

If you want a number, you should not call `toFixed()` at all. But you will have to accept that the number will not necessarily have exactly the decimal precision you want.  That's just the way floating point numbers work with computers.  You can't force a decimal precision and still have a number data type.

If you must have decimal precision, then you should accept that you can't have a number type in Firestore, and instead store the data in a way that preserves the decimal precision that you need. This sort of thing is very common in systems that store currency values that need to be 100% accurate and can't split pennies. This is something you should research and understand what your option are, because failing to store currency values properly can lead to accounting errors which could be bad for business that depends on accurate values.

Comment: It should be possible to store a price as an integer number of cents (in this case 550) without any rounding errors. A string shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @QuantumWiz Certainly that is one of many options available here.

Comment: I removed toFixed as this function is only used at load time (not a calculated value yet)